Set up the Screen resolution since the start up phase
I am using a UHD TV as screen of my mini PC with Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
I want to set up the Screen resolution since the start up phase,
with below values:
1920 x 1080 (16:9) - Scale 125%
Can someone help me to identify the file I need to be modified,
and the statement I need to add or modify.
Thanks in advance of your support
AloSyl66

Do you mean that when you start the computer that is the settings for the video? Have you not set this in the Display Settings of the OS? Please add more details as it is not clear what you have done or tried.

I think you are asking to set screen resolution during the boot process. This could result in boot problems but can be done by modifying grub. See https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/05/screen-resolution-grub-boot-menu-ubuntu/ Good luck if you decide to take the risk.
